C compiler identification is unknown when building a docker image
I am trying to build onnxruntime for an armv7 platform. I have made the following Dockerfile:
# Use an ARMv7 compatible base image
FROM arm32v7/ubuntu:24.04 as builder

WORKDIR /workspace

# Install necessary packages for setting up Python and other dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    libc6-dev-armhf-cross \
    libstdc++-10-dev-armhf-cross \
    linux-libc-dev-armhf-cross\
    python3 \
    python3-dev \
    python3-venv \
    python3-pip \
    build-essential \
    cmake \
    ninja-build \
    libopenblas-dev \
    wget \
    curl \
    ca-certificates \
    git \
    pkg-config \
    libatlas-base-dev \
    gfortran

# Update CA certificates
RUN update-ca-certificates

# Create a virtual environment and activate it
RUN python3 -m venv /workspace/venv
ENV PATH="/workspace/venv/bin:$PATH"

# Now, use Python and Pip from the virtual environment:
RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install numpy Cython

# Set up environment variables for the compiler and qemu
ENV QEMU_EXECVE=1
COPY --from=multiarch/qemu-user-static:x86_64-aarch64 /usr/bin/qemu-aarch64-static /usr/bin/

# Download and install the ARMv7 toolchain (Linaro)
RUN wget --no-check-certificate https://releases.linaro.org/components/toolchain/binaries/latest-7/arm-linux-gnueabihf/gcc-linaro-7.5.0-2019.12-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf.tar.xz && \
    tar -xJf gcc-linaro-7.5.0-2019.12-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf.tar.xz -C /opt/ && \
    mv /opt/gcc-linaro-7.5.0-2019.12-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf /opt/gcc-linaro
ENV PATH="/opt/gcc-linaro/bin:${PATH}"
ENV CMAKE_C_COMPILER="/opt/gcc-linaro/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc"
ENV CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER="/opt/gcc-linaro/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++"

# Clone ONNX Runtime specific version
RUN git clone --recursive https://github.com/microsoft/onnxruntime.git && \
    cd onnxruntime && \
    git checkout v1.17.0 && \
    git submodule update --init --recursive

# Set up the toolchain cmake file
RUN echo "SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)\n\
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION 1)\n\
SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc)\n\
SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++)\n\
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)\n\
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)\n\
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)\n\
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PACKAGE ONLY)\n" > /workspace/onnxruntime/tool.cmake

# Build ONNX Runtime
WORKDIR /workspace/onnxruntime
RUN ./build.sh --config Release --allow_running_as_root --update \
    --build --parallel --build_shared_lib \
    --cmake_extra_defines CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/workspace/onnxruntime/tool.cmake


# Set up final image
FROM arm32v7/ubuntu:24.04
COPY --from=builder /workspace/onnxruntime/build/Linux/Release /usr/local/lib/onnxruntime

# Set environment variables
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib/onnxruntime/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

# Set work directory
WORKDIR /data

# Entry command
CMD ["bash"]

I build it with this line docker build --platform=linux/arm/v7 -t onnxruntime-armv7 ..
I get the following error:
 => ERROR [builder 13/13] RUN ./build.sh --config Release --allow_running_as_root --update     --build --parallel --build_shared_lib     --cmake_extra_defines CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/workspace/onnxruntime/tool.cmake              5.9s 
------
 > [builder 13/13] RUN ./build.sh --config Release --allow_running_as_root --update     --build --parallel --build_shared_lib     --cmake_extra_defines CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/workspace/onnxruntime/tool.cmake:
1.252 2024-04-15 14:30:55,763 tools_python_utils [INFO] - flatbuffers module is not installed. parse_config will not be available
1.300 2024-04-15 14:30:55,813 build [DEBUG] - Command line arguments:
1.300   --build_dir /workspace/onnxruntime/build/Linux --config Release --allow_running_as_root --update --build --parallel --build_shared_lib --cmake_extra_defines CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/workspace/onnxruntime/tool.cmake
1.349 2024-04-15 14:30:55,862 build [INFO] - Build started
1.349 2024-04-15 14:30:55,863 build [INFO] - git submodule sync --recursive
1.975 Synchronizing submodule url for 'cmake/external/emsdk'
2.020 Synchronizing submodule url for 'cmake/external/libprotobuf-mutator'
2.063 Synchronizing submodule url for 'cmake/external/onnx'
2.119 Synchronizing submodule url for 'cmake/external/onnx/third_party/benchmark'
2.164 Synchronizing submodule url for 'cmake/external/onnx/third_party/pybind11'
2.216 2024-04-15 14:30:56,729 build [INFO] - git submodule update --init --recursive
3.153 2024-04-15 14:30:57,666 build [INFO] - Generating CMake build tree
3.155 2024-04-15 14:30:57,669 build [INFO] - /usr/bin/cmake /workspace/onnxruntime/cmake -Donnxruntime_RUN_ONNX_TESTS=OFF -Donnxruntime_GENERATE_TEST_REPORTS=ON -DPython_EXECUTABLE=/workspace/venv/bin/python3 -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/wo
rkspace/venv/bin/python3 -Donnxruntime_USE_MIMALLOC=OFF -Donnxruntime_ENABLE_PYTHON=OFF -Donnxruntime_BUILD_CSHARP=OFF -Donnxruntime_BUILD_JAVA=OFF -Donnxruntime_BUILD_NODEJS=OFF -Donnxruntime_BUILD_OBJC=OFF -Donnxruntime_BUILD_SHAR
ED_LIB=ON -Donnxruntime_BUILD_APPLE_FRAMEWORK=OFF -Donnxruntime_USE_DNNL=OFF -Donnxruntime_USE_NNAPI_BUILTIN=OFF -Donnxruntime_USE_RKNPU=OFF -Donnxruntime_USE_LLVM=OFF -Donnxruntime_ENABLE_MICROSOFT_INTERNAL=OFF -Donnxruntime_USE_VI
TISAI=OFF -Donnxruntime_USE_TENSORRT=OFF -Donnxruntime_USE_TENSORRT_BUILTIN_PARSER=ON -Donnxruntime_USE_TVM=OFF -Donnxruntime_TVM_CUDA_RUNTIME=OFF -Donnxruntime_TVM_USE_HASH=OFF -Donnxruntime_USE_MIGRAPHX=OFF -Donnxruntime_DISABLE_C
ONTRIB_OPS=OFF -Donnxruntime_DISABLE_ML_OPS=OFF -Donnxruntime_DISABLE_RTTI=OFF -Donnxruntime_DISABLE_EXCEPTIONS=OFF -Donnxruntime_MINIMAL_BUILD=OFF -Donnxruntime_EXTENDED_MINIMAL_BUILD=OFF -Donnxruntime_MINIMAL_BUILD_CUSTOM_OPS=OFF 
-Donnxruntime_REDUCED_OPS_BUILD=OFF -Donnxruntime_ENABLE_LANGUAGE_INTEROP_OPS=OFF -Donnxruntime_USE_DML=OFF -Donnxruntime_USE_WINML=OFF -Donnxruntime_BUILD_MS_EXPERIMENTAL_OPS=OFF -Donnxruntime_USE_TELEMETRY=OFF -Donnxruntime_ENABLE
_LTO=OFF -Donnxruntime_USE_ACL=OFF -Donnxruntime_USE_ACL_1902=OFF -Donnxruntime_USE_ACL_1905=OFF -Donnxruntime_USE_ACL_1908=OFF -Donnxruntime_USE_ACL_2002=OFF -Donnxruntime_USE_ACL_2308=OFF -Donnxruntime_USE_ARMNN=OFF -Donnxruntime_
ARMNN_RELU_USE_CPU=ON -Donnxruntime_ARMNN_BN_USE_CPU=ON -Donnxruntime_USE_JSEP=OFF -Donnxruntime_ENABLE_NVTX_PROFILE=OFF -Donnxruntime_ENABLE_TRAINING=OFF -Donnxruntime_ENABLE_TRAINING_OPS=OFF -Donnxruntime_ENABLE_TRAINING_APIS=OFF 
-Donnxruntime_ENABLE_CPU_FP16_OPS=OFF -Donnxruntime_USE_NCCL=OFF -Donnxruntime_BUILD_BENCHMARKS=OFF -Donnxruntime_USE_ROCM=OFF -DOnnxruntime_GCOV_COVERAGE=OFF -Donnxruntime_USE_MPI=OFF -Donnxruntime_ENABLE_MEMORY_PROFILE=OFF -Donnxr
untime_ENABLE_CUDA_LINE_NUMBER_INFO=OFF -Donnxruntime_USE_CUDA_NHWC_OPS=OFF -Donnxruntime_BUILD_WEBASSEMBLY_STATIC_LIB=OFF -Donnxruntime_ENABLE_WEBASSEMBLY_EXCEPTION_CATCHING=ON -Donnxruntime_ENABLE_WEBASSEMBLY_API_EXCEPTION_CATCHIN
G=OFF -Donnxruntime_ENABLE_WEBASSEMBLY_EXCEPTION_THROWING=ON -Donnxruntime_WEBASSEMBLY_RUN_TESTS_IN_BROWSER=OFF -Donnxruntime_ENABLE_WEBASSEMBLY_THREADS=OFF -Donnxruntime_ENABLE_WEBASSEMBLY_DEBUG_INFO=OFF -Donnxruntime_ENABLE_WEBASS
EMBLY_PROFILING=OFF -Donnxruntime_ENABLE_LAZY_TENSOR=OFF -Donnxruntime_ENABLE_EXTERNAL_CUSTOM_OP_SCHEMAS=OFF -Donnxruntime_ENABLE_CUDA_PROFILING=OFF -Donnxruntime_ENABLE_ROCM_PROFILING=OFF -Donnxruntime_USE_XNNPACK=OFF -Donnxruntime
_USE_WEBNN=OFF -Donnxruntime_USE_CANN=OFF -Donnxruntime_USE_TRITON_KERNEL=OFF -Donnxruntime_DISABLE_FLOAT8_TYPES=OFF -Donnxruntime_DISABLE_SPARSE_TENSORS=OFF -Donnxruntime_DISABLE_OPTIONAL_TYPE=OFF -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/workspace/onnxruntime/tool.cmake -DCMAKE_TLS_VERIFY=ON -DFETCHCONTENT_QUIET=OFF -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/workspace/onnxruntime/build/Linux/Release/installed
3.317 CMake Deprecation Warning at CMakeLists.txt:14 (cmake_policy):
3.317   The OLD behavior for policy CMP0104 will be removed from a future version
3.318   of CMake.
3.318
3.318   The cmake-policies(7) manual explains that the OLD behaviors of all
3.318   policies are deprecated and that a policy should be set to OLD only under
3.318   specific short-term circumstances.  Projects should be ported to the NEW
3.318   behavior and not rely on setting a policy to OLD.
3.318
3.318
4.007 -- The C compiler identification is unknown
4.595 -- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
4.689 -- The ASM compiler identification is unknown
4.699 -- Found assembler: /opt/gcc-linaro/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc
4.769 -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
5.307 -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - failed
5.307 -- Check for working C compiler: /opt/gcc-linaro/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc
5.722 -- Check for working C compiler: /opt/gcc-linaro/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc - broken
5.723 CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.28/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:67 (message):
5.723   The C compiler
5.723
5.723     "/opt/gcc-linaro/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc"
5.723
5.723   is not able to compile a simple test program.
5.723
5.723   It fails with the following output:
5.723
5.723     Change Dir: '/workspace/onnxruntime/build/Linux/Release/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-6M4912'
5.723
5.723     Run Build Command(s): /usr/bin/cmake -E env VERBOSE=1 /usr/bin/gmake -f Makefile cmTC_9a794/fast
5.723     /usr/bin/gmake  -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_9a794.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_9a794.dir/build
5.723     gmake[1]: Entering directory '/workspace/onnxruntime/build/Linux/Release/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-6M4912'
5.723     Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_9a794.dir/testCCompiler.c.o
5.723     /opt/gcc-linaro/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc    -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_9a794.dir/testCCompiler.c.o -c /workspace/onnxruntime/build/Linux/Release/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-6M4912/testCCompiler.c
5.723     gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_9a794.dir/build.make:78: CMakeFiles/cmTC_9a794.dir/testCCompiler.c.o] Error 127
5.723     gmake[1]: Leaving directory '/workspace/onnxruntime/build/Linux/Release/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-6M4912'
5.723     gmake: *** [Makefile:127: cmTC_9a794/fast] Error 2
5.723
5.723
5.723
5.723
5.723
5.723   CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
5.723 Call Stack (most recent call first):
5.723   CMakeLists.txt:20 (project)
5.723
5.723 
5.728 -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!


I am building the Dockerfile on a Windows machine and I want it to run on a Raspberry Pi.
I setup the toolchain CMake file in the Dockerfile and I expected that to point CMake to the right compilers, but obviously they still aren't being identified.
